# How to build an ffmpeg-old-version(0.10.4) libraries for ios supporting arm64 architecture?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, arm64

I'm building the ffmpeg libraries to support arm64 architecture in iOS app. For some reason, I can't use the newest ffmpeg version. I have to use the very old version ffmpeg(0.10.4)

After reading all the tutorial of building ffmpeg libraries on the internet, [this](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) (https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) script is probably the best script for me. However, I can't build the arm64 libraries from ffmpeg-0.10.4 by the script, the error message is

> building arm64...
>
> GNU assembler not found, install gas-preprocessor
>
> If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
>   version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
>   ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
>   Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
>   solving the problem.

What I changed the script are:

> SOURCE="ffmpeg-2.6.3" to SOURCE="ffmpeg-0.10.4"
>
> ARCHS="arm64 armv7 x86_64 i386" to ARCHS="arm64 armv7"
>
> DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="6.0" to DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="7.0"

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's a waste of time attempting to use such an old version. Why can't you use a modern version?

Comment: I've tried to use the latest version, and my app can't be compiled and with more error and warning...

Comment: Apple only accept the updated app supporting arm64 after June 1. So I need to make my app to support arm64 ASAP. After that, I'll try to use the new version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Did you check the contents of `config.log` file. If you can please upload the error message given at the bottom of this file. You can also have a look at https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer/, i builded the latest ffmpeg using their scripts.

Comment: I'd compiled the newest version ffmpeg successfully. It turns out that there are some typos in the .sh file...